# bash: how to source array from section config file after sed?

Tags: arrays, bash, config

my config file:

```
[general] 

VARDIR="../var"
LOGDIR="../var/log"
HOST=$(hostname)
DAY=monday

[animals]

CATS=("cat" "food" "eur" "100" "150" ),
DOGS=("dog" "food" "usd" "5000" "8000"),
```

in other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347695/how-to-read-config-files-with-section-in-bash-shell) i found this:

```
sed -n '1,/animals/d;/\[/,$d;/^$/d;p;'
```

and works well:

```
test@test_server$: sed -n '1,/animals/d;/\[/,$d;/^$/d;p;' config_file

CATS=("cat" "food" "eur" "100" "150" )
DOGS=("dog" "food" "usd" "5000" "8000")
```

but i can't source a section in my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source  $(sed -n '1,/animals/d;/\[/,$d;/^$/d;p;' config) 
echo $DOGS
```

give me

error:
./testit.sh: line 3: CATS=("cat": No such file or directory

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`source` requires a file for an argument.  Thus, replace:

```
source  $(sed -n '1,/animals/d;/\[/,$d;/^$/d;p;' config)
```

With:

```
source  <(sed -n '1,/animals/d;/\[/,$d;/^$/d;p;' config)
```

The bash construct `<(...)` is called *process substitution*.  It creates a file-like object that `source` can read from.  It is in contrast to `$(...)` which is called *command substitution* which creates a string.

Answer (score 0):

`source` takes a file as an argument. The expression:

`$(sed -n '1,/animals/d;/\[/,$d;/^$/d;p;' config)`

isn't a file.

You can just rewrite this as (note using -i for inplace modification of file):

```
sed -i -n '1,/animals/d;/\[/,$d;/^$/d;p;' config
source config
```

Answer (score 0):

We should use `eval` to execute the result of sed command, and don't forget double quotes.

```
#!/bin/bash
eval "$(sed -n '1,/animals/d;/\[/,$d;/^$/d;p;' config)"
echo $DOGS
echo "${DOGS[2]}"
```

BTW, The last comma in config file should be deleted.