# grep get text from specific section only from bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following config file:

```
[general]
a=b
b=c
...
mykey=myvalue
n=X

[prod]
a=b
b=c
mykey=myvalue2
...
```

I want to get `mykey` only from `[general]` section.

What I have been tried is the follow:

```
cat my.config | grep mykey
```

And as except I got two results:

```
mykey=myvalue
mykey=myvalue2
```

`[general]` section isn't always appear on the first part of the config file.

How can I get `mykey` that appear under `[general]` section using linux commands?

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347695/how-to-read-config-files-with-section-in-bash-shell

Comment: If ```[general]``` is before/above any other section then simply ```-m1``` for grep is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the values between [general] and the next squared parameter.

```
awk '/^\[/{f=0} f; /\[general\]/{f=1}' file.config | grep mykey
```

Comment: can you explain please '/^\[/{f=0} f; /\[general\]/{f=1}' ? Thanks!!\

Comment: With  `/^\[/` you are matching `/something/` starting (regex ^) with `[` at the beginning, then match `[general]`. f can be any word, the values 0, 1 are true and false, I think. You can use `awk '/^\[general\]/,/^\[/' file.config` as well, but this will print the words in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one with awk:

```
$ awk -v RS="" '            # process empty line separated blocks
$1=="[general]" {           # if a block starts with a key string
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)      # iterate records or fields in this case
        if($i~/^mykey=/) {  # find the key
            print $i        # and output the field
            exit            # once found, no point in continuing the search
        }
}' file
```

Output:

```
mykey=myvalue
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use python script

ini2arr.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(sys.stdin)

for sec in config.sections():
    print "declare -A %s" % (sec)
    for key, val in config.items(sec):
        print '%s[%s]="%s"' % (sec, key, val)
```

then

```
eval "$(cat t.ini  | ./ini2arr.py)"

echo ${general["mykey"]}
```

**EDIT OR:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ConfigParser

section_filter = sys.argv[1]
key_filter = sys.argv[2]

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(sys.stdin)

print '%s[%s]="%s"' % (section_filter, key_filter, config.get(section_filter, key_filter))
```

then

```
cat t.ini  | ./ini2arr.py prod a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `awk` solution (using standard linux awk/gawk)

```
/\[general\]/,/^$/ {if ($0 ~ "mykey") print}
```

#### Explanation

```
/\[general\]/,/^$/  # match lines range : starting with "[general]" and ending with "" (empty line)
{                   # for each line in range
  if ($0 ~ "mykey") # if line match regex pattern "mykey"
    print $0        # print the line
}
```